# Center LocationComponent at bottom of view

Tags: android, mapbox

i'm looking for a way to center the

```
LocationComponent
```

at the bottom of my mapbox map. I know that there is a react native SDK version for this:

```
<Mapbox.MapView userLocationVerticalAlignment{UserLocationVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM}>
```

since react native uses android / java, i'm pretty sure there has to be an android equivalent for that :-).

Since there is neither a method for the

```
com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent
```

nor for the

```
com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap
```

and nothing about

```
com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdate
```

that takes an offset or something as input parameter, i'm kinda lost. Thanks in advance for any suggestions on that topic!

Br, Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to change the centered position of the `LocationComponent` you can use the `LocationComponentOptions#padding` like this:

```
int[] padding;
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
  padding = new int[] {0, 750, 0, 0};
} else {
  padding = new int[] {0, 250, 0, 0};
}

LocationComponentOptions options = LocationComponentOptions.builder(this)
  .padding(padding)
  .build();
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank mate